# How to allow a route to a user as long as he has the good role?

Tags: 8, routes, users

Maybe this is a noob question but here goes:

I have a menu a menu that contains four links. However, I need one of the items to be accessible only if the current user has "beneficiary" as role.

Since the user's 'roles' is an array containing all kind of roles, how can I set my route in a way that as long as the user has the correct role ?

IE, let's say that a random user has the following:

```
$user['roles'] = ['authenticated', 'beneficiary', 'elected'];
```

and would pass, but another random user having the following:

```
$user['roles'] = ['authenticated', 'elected'];
```

wouldn't.

I'm pretty sure there is a way but I can't find explicitely what I'm looking for in Drupal's documentation

Thank you in advance

Comment: So essentially you need to allow access to a route if the current user has the "beneficiary" role?

Comment: Is this Drupal 8? Are you defining your route in a custom entity routing.yml file?

Comment: @Clive > yes, that's right, and yes this is Drupal 8 (I'll add a tag)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I've never personally tried this, but it looks like in your routing.yml file, you can specify a _role permission under requirements:

https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/structure-of-routes

```
my_module.your_route:
  path: '/your_menu_path'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\path\to\your\controller'
    _title: 'Menu title'
  requirements:
    _role: 'beneficiary'
```

Comment: I just had issues wether to place it since there was several possibilities, but now it works fine, I get 404 with a wrong user, thank you !

Comment: You can also specify multiple permissions by separating them with ',' (comma) for AND logic or '+' (plus) for OR logic (e.g., _role: 'administrator,beneficiary').